# Pullbacks as manifolds versus ones as topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, category-theory, manifolds

Let $Y_1\overset{f}{\longrightarrow}X\overset{f_2}{\longleftarrow} Y_2$ be smooth maps with a common target. Suppose that we have a pullback $Z$ of the diagram in (Mfd).

Questions:

1. Suppose that we have a manifold $Z$ satisfying the universal property of pullbacks. Is the subset $\{(y_1,y_2) \in Y_1 \times Y_2 \mid f_1(y_1)=f_2(y_2)\}$ a submanifold of $Y_1 \times Y_2$ diffeomorphic to $Z$?
2. Is a pullback in (Mfd) always a pullback in (Top)?
3. Does the forgetful functor (Mfd)$\to$(Top) preserve all small (or finite) limits?
4. If you know a good reference to categorical properties of manifolds, please let me know.

Note:

- (Mfd) is the category of smooth manifolds and smooth maps.
- (Top) is the category of topological spaces and continuous maps.
- In my question, a pullback is a limit in the sense of the theory of categories, i.e. a pullback is a manifold/topological space satisfying the universal property of pullback.

Comment: I slightly modified Q1.

Comment: Related (but not identical): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322485/fiber-products-of-manifolds

Comment: I have asked the same question at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/124311/pullbacks-as-manifolds-versus-ones-as-topological-spaces